# Maintaing state of page angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am adding some number of textbox controls on a button click and entering some text on each textbox, then am navigating to another one page, and coming back to my initial page. am not able to see my textboxes...

Is there any way to keep my textboxes and values of each textbox in angularjs?

Comment: I think you can create a service in AngularJS to store the data from controller. And when you switch back to that particular page, you can fetch the data inside that service and put back to controller. Notice that when you switch the page but still inside AngularJS app, controller data will be destroyed but service data won't.

Comment: Can you pls give any sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a service or factory to communicate between different controllers or in your case page.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21920241/4067825). Hope it gives you some idea.

Thanks